# Check whether a user owns a service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

I have service and servicebooking models. I want to be able to check whether the current user owns a service and display the servicebookings that have been made for that users services.

I am trying to display this in a myservicebookings page.

This is the myservicebookings action in the servicebookings_controller, in the commented line Iam trying to check whether the current user is the owner of any of the servicebookings made or the owner of any of the services booked, I need to advise on how to go about this?

```
def myservicebookings
   @servicebookings = current_user.services.servicebooking.find(params[:user_id])
   @servicebookings = current_user.servicebookings.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

This is the myservicebookings view, Iam trying to display both incoming/outgoing requests for services for the current user:

```
<h1>My Service bookings</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable "date" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "time" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "service name" %></th>
  </tr>
<% if @servicebookings.any? %>

  <h4>Incoming requests:</h4>

  <% @servicebookings.each do |servicebooking| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= servicebooking.date %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.time %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.service_name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "View this booking", servicebooking_path(servicebooking) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

  <h4>Outgoing requests:</h4>

  <% @servicebookings.each do |servicebooking| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= servicebooking.date %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.time %></td>
      <td><%= servicebooking.service_name %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "View this booking", servicebooking_path(servicebooking) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
<%else%>
<%= "You have no incoming or outgoing service booking requests"%>
<%end%>
<%= will_paginate @servicebookings %>
<%= link_to "Homepage", :controller => "welcome", :action => "index" %>
```

Servicebooking model:

```
class Servicebooking < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :service_id, :date, :time, :user_id, :service_name, :accept_booking
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :service

  def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
```

end

Services model:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :avatar2, :avatar3, :avatar4, :name, :date_available, :time_available, :description, :price, :size, :company_name, :company_details
  has_attached_file :avatar, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  has_attached_file :avatar2, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  has_attached_file :avatar3, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  has_attached_file :avatar4, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :servicebookings


  def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    scoped
  end
end
end
```

Thanks guys, any help is appreciated.

Comment: how does your model look like? Do you have relationship between `User` and `Service`? e.g User has_many :services?

Comment: your controller overwrites the `@servicebookings` instance variable

Comment: Yes, I have the User has_many :services relationship in both directions Rakesh, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your controller. Assuming that there is a `owner` method on `ServiceBooking` and `Service`

```
def myservicebookings
    @servicebookings = current_user.servicebookings.includes(:user).search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])

    owns_servicebooking = current_user.servicebookings.detect do |sb| 
        sb.user == current_user 
    end
    owns_service = current_user.services.detect do |s| 
        s.user == current_user 
    end
    @is_an_owner = owns_servicebooking and owns_service
end
```

`detect` returns an object if it matches the block and since it is ruby you can use it in a boolean expression to get what you want.

UPDATE: added controller method to the code example above. To use it in your view something like:

```
<% if @is_an_owner %>
    <markup/>
<% end %>
```

I am pretty certain that this is not the best option in your case but I don't know enough about your stuff to suggest otherwise. It may be a start though. You may want to consider putting parts of this down to the model or into a helper method instead.

Comment: Hey Froderik, I havent got an owner method??

Comment: I didn't see your model when I wrote the answer. You seem to have a `user` method that you can use. Is the user always the owner?

Comment: Hey Froderik, yes a service does not exist without a user creating it, they can have many services and I want to list the booking requests for the logged in users' services if any?

Comment: so how do you know that a user owns it? It doesn't seem to be in the model. Or is it not a persistent state?

Comment: There is a user_id column in the services and servicebookings table

Comment: yep and the should be the services user as you described before. but how do you know who is the owner?

Comment: ok so I need to create an owner method in the service and servicebooking controllers?

Comment: I don't know much about your use case but I guess you want to persist ownership? Then you should have another relation between the service and servicebooking models to the user table called owner. How is the owner different from the current user relation?

Comment: A user creates a service and can have many services. A user can book the service of another user through a servicebooking. A user can accept the booking for their service from another user

Comment: if so a user and a owner is the same thing and you can replace owner with user in the code above.

Comment: Hey Froderik thanks for your help I will be accepting your answer, how would I integrate this into my myservicebooings method above?